# I'm getting a UFuncTypeError when doing a Linear Regression with sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression

This is a simple code, so I'm missing something pretty obvious:

```
print(X.dtype)
print(y.dtype)

lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X, y)
print("Score: " + str(lin_reg.score(X,y)))
print("Coefs: " + str(lin_reg.coef_))
print("Intercept: " + str(lin_reg.intercept_))
```

and the outpu is:

```
float64
int64
Score: 0.8725949819648744
Coefs: [[825.09663073]]
Intercept: [-122.41197463]
```

Now, the problem is when I try to predict. First I get a sample:

```
x_sample = X[:144]
y_sample = y[:144]

print("Predictions: " + lin_reg.predict(x_sample))
```

which give-me this error that I don't understand:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-791-1d189ee47b31> in <module>
      2 y_sample = y[:144]
      3 
----> 4 print("Predictions: " + lin_reg.predict(x_sample))

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got it!

The problem has nothing to do with the arrays. It's in the print method:

```
print("Predictions: " + str(lin_reg.predict(x_sample)))
```